# I got this error in AndroidStudio while trying to download a repo from github. (i created the repo on a mac now im on windows)

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio-3.0

VFS name enumerator corrupted: nameId(=5396158) is not found in enumerator (=null)

Its a private repo i tried to clone it in Androidstudio from VersionControl and both OS and Windows git and Android versions are latest versions.

**Edit: I opened a new project and tried to implement implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0")
implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1")
and i got the same error message i dont think error is about git or smth it happens when i try to sync something.**

Comment: Instead of add in the message again and again you have added more details about if it is a public or private repo or if you have tried to clone it manually via git cmdline. Also OS git version and Android Studio version would be good zk know. So please edit your question and improve it.